# ActiveX Not Register

Tags: javascript, c#, activex, internet-explorer-10, activexobject

I'm trying to create a ActiveX plugin for IE. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.olavaukan.com/2010/08/creating-an-activex-control-in-net-using-c/). It was working few months ago. But today I tried to create new project by following that tutorial but its not working today. Please help me to solve this issue.

following is my code.

Thanks in advance

```
namespace AxControls
{
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("1FC0D50A-4803-4f97-94FB-2F41717F558D")]
[ProgId("AxControls.HelloWorld")]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IHelloWorld))]
public class HelloWorld : UserControl, IHelloWorld, IObjectSafety
{
    #region IHelloWorld Members

    public string GetText()
    {
        return "Hello ActiveX World!";
    }

    #endregion

    #region IObjectSafety Members

    public enum ObjectSafetyOptions
    {
        INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER = 0x00000001,
        INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA = 0x00000002,
        INTERFACE_USES_DISPEX = 0x00000004,
        INTERFACE_USES_SECURITY_MANAGER = 0x00000008
    };

    public int GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, out int pdwSupportedOptions, out int pdwEnabledOptions)
    {
        ObjectSafetyOptions m_options = ObjectSafetyOptions.INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER | ObjectSafetyOptions.INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA;
        pdwSupportedOptions = (int)m_options;
        pdwEnabledOptions = (int)m_options;
        return 0;
    }

    public int SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, int dwOptionSetMask, int dwEnabledOptions)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

---

```
namespace AxControls
{
[ComImport()]
[Guid("3384A707-F5DB-43D2-9039-9912998C912B")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IObjectSafety
{
    [PreserveSig()]
    int GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, out int pdwSupportedOptions, out int pdwEnabledOptions);

    [PreserveSig()]
    int SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, int dwOptionSetMask, int dwEnabledOptions);
}
}
```

then I have created a separate Setup Project in Visual studio and get the `primary output` and enable `VsdrpCom` to auto register when installing the setup.

to ensure the installation is success, i have check the `Manage Add-on` section in Internet Explorer.

I'm using `Windows 8 OS` and `IE 10 Browser`

Comment: have you signed your ActiveX? I mean to say, are you getting any error while debugging JavaScript in IE? 

i.e. Automation server can not create an object or something?

Comment: May be you need to change your IE setting to run add-on / ActiveX?
please check out settings in security tab as well as Advanced settings tab.